# How to change the return type of AsynTask?

Tags: android, asynchronous

I'm very new to programming and I have extended the `AsynTask` class like this:

```
private class HttpCalls extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,JSONObject>
```

and I have overrided the method like this:

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... voids) {
     . . .
     return jsonObject;
}
```

but when I call `new HttpCalls().execute()` I want the return type to be of `JSONObject` but what I get is :

```
AsyncTask<Void,Void,JSONObject>
```

how do I change this to `JSONObject`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asyctask never returns any result to you. You must retrieve the result in onPostExecute() of asynctask.

Comment: Please improve your AACEPTance rate....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class YouClass {

public JSONObject result;

   private class HttpCalls extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,JSONObject>
       {
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
       super.onPostExecute(result);
               YouClass.result = result;
       } } }
```

Comment: The user who posted the question doesnt respond to ur answers. He wont upvote/Accept/comment ur answer......

Comment: I wish I could write something like this: 
`JSONObject j = new HttpCalls().execute();` but still I get incompatible errors.

Comment: Oh! Alright, then how come I take that `jsonResult` out of this call?

Comment: check my updated make HttpCalls to inner class of youclass but easy is just move your code to onPostExecute

Answer (score 1):

Doing like this

```
JSONObject j = new HttpCalls().execute();
```

Will not return actually a `JSONObject`. It will return an `AsyncTask` itself.

You should catch the result in `onPostExecute()`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {

    super.onPostExecute(result);

    // Do some stuffs
}
```

Comment: The user who posted the question doesnt respond to ur answers. He wont upvote/Accept/comment ur answer......

Comment: I wish I could write something like this: 
`JSONObject j = new HttpCalls().execute();` but still I get incompatible errors.

Comment: @sriram No, It will return `AsyncTask` itself. That's why you're getting that error